# How to determine the cause of a VBA SQL syntax problem?

Tags: sql, vba

I'm totally new to VBA but I don't really have the time to find a solution myself. I have the following SQL String in VBA and it just doesn't work (it tells me that it expects an end of statement):

```
MySQLStr = "INSERT INTO Table (Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4, Field5, Field6, Field7, Field8)" & _
                    "Values ("16", "13", "1", '" & FormatSQL(myItem.Body) & "', '"Left(FormatSQL(myItem.Subject), 50) & "', "Text" , '" & Date & "', "1")"
```

Comment: As far as I can see you need the ampersand in front of the Left () function and double quotes around the word Text and 1 (the last parameter).

Comment: print your sql and fire that result in mysql tool to see where is the error.

Comment: Are you sure you want to store the numbers like `16` and `13` as Strings?

Comment: ah yeah you're right, i missed the ampersand. What do you mean by double quotes, i already have them ("Text" and "1")?

Comment: @FunThomas for the moment yes, what would be the alternative?

Comment: @KoushikRoy sounds good, can you give me a hint how i do that (Sorry, like i mentioned i'm really new to VBA)?

Comment: @BrianF. It they are ment to be numbers, store them as numbers. But that depends on how the fields are defined in your DBMS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were many problems with your SQL statement.  If you have time, compare the two statements as a learning exercise.  Here is my attempt at what you need:

```sql
   MySQLStr = "INSERT INTO Table (Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4, Field5, Field6, Field7, Field8) " & _
              "Values ('16', '13', '1', '" & FormatSQL(myItem.Body) & "', '" & Left(FormatSQL(myItem.Subject), 50) & "', 'Text', '" & Date & "', '1')"
```

Better yet, you should really be using Parameters instead of building a complex string.  It's a little more code, but easier to build secure sql statements.

Comment: Thank you so much Brian, i will definitely do that. Normally i would try to learn about the Syntax first but i just didn't have the time today, so Thanks you for helping me out